# Given 2 arrays of non-negative numbers, find the minimum sum of products

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given two arrays `A` and `B`, each containing `n` non-negative numbers, remove `a>0` elements from the end of A and `b>0` elements from the end of B. Evaluate the cost of such an operation as `X*Y` where `X` is the sum of the `a` elements removed from `A` and `Y` the sum of the `b` elements removed from `B`. Keep doing this until both arrays are empty. The goal is to minimize the total cost.

Using dynamic programming and the fact that an optimal strategy will always take exactly one element from either `A` or `B` I can find an O(n^3) solution. Now I'm curious to know if there is an even faster solution to this problem?

EDIT: Stealing an example from @recursive in the comments:

> A = [1,9,1] and B = [1, 9, 1]. Possible to do with a cost of 20. (1) *
>   (1 + 9) + (9 + 1) * (1)

Comment: According to me the solution should  select last two elements of each array  sum them ad then add. O(n).

Comment: If I'm wrong then please clarify the problem statement to me

Comment: According to your statement we have to remove from the end of A and the end of B

Comment: If you are solving the problem on some online coding website , can you please share the link, it'll help me to explain you better

Comment: Still your problem doesn't makes sense. Just keep popping numbers from both array one by one multiply them and add it to sum. Since (a1+a2)*(b1+b2) >= a1*b1 + a2 *b2. Hope you get my point.

Comment: @udhy: That doesn't always yield an optimal removal order: e.g. `A = [1,9,1]` and `B = [1, 9, 1]`.  Your approach yields a cost of 83, but it's possible to do with a cost of 20. (1) * (1 + 9) + (9 + 1) * (1)

Comment: Yeah, there's a quadratic-time solution.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Interesting! Do you have a reference?

Comment: No, but this is an undergraduate exercise in dynamic programming, so I didn't look for one.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Ok, does this exercise go by any name so I can find it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's `O(n^2)`. Let `CostA(i, j)` be the min cost of eliminating `A[1..i], B[1..j]` in such a way that the first removal takes only one element from `B`. Let `CostB(i, j)` be the min cost of eliminating `A[1..i], B[1..j]` in such a way that the first removal takes only one element from `A`. We have mutually recursive recurrences

```
CostA(i, j) = A[i] * B[j] + min(CostA(i - 1, j),
                                CostA(i - 1, j - 1),
                                CostB(i - 1, j - 1))
CostB(i, j) = A[i] * B[j] + min(CostB(i, j - 1),
                                CostA(i - 1, j - 1),
                                CostB(i - 1, j - 1))
```

with base cases

```
CostA(0, 0) = 0
CostA(>0, 0) = infinity
CostA(0, >0) = infinity
CostB(0, 0) = 0
CostB(>0, 0) = infinity
CostB(0, >0) = infinity.
```

The answer is `min(CostA(n, n), CostB(n, n))`.

Comment: Actually you only need one `Cost(i, j)` where
`Cost(i, j) = A[i] * B[j] + min(Cost(i, j - 1), Cost(i - 1, j), Cost(i - 1, j - 1))`

Comment: Implemented and verified both solutions. Can confirm they work properly.